# deletion of one past end element in map and segmentation fault

Tags: c++

When I *tried* to delete `end()` element from the `map` using `erase` I got no issues in compilation but on later printing the `map.begin()` key/mapped_value I got segmentation fault:

```
 //RELEVANT HEADERS

 //main function starts

 map<int, string> m;
 m[0] = "hello";
 m[1] = "Mello";

 m.erase(m.end());

 cout<<(m.begin())->second;
```

**OUTPUT:** `Segmentation fault`

My question is: on trying to delete the `end()` element nothing would've happened to the structure of map `m` as `end` refers to one past the real end element, so what really triggered that `segmentation fault` as the memory structure still holds same as before deletion.

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff I have mentioned the same in my question.

Comment: In my pc without the printing I got segmantation fault too. You have to pass a valid iterator to the function erase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in e.g. [cppreference's documentation on `std::map::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase), the iterator passed to it must be a valid iterator into the container that `erase` is called on and it has to be dereferencable.

The `end()` iterator is not dereferencable. Therefore passing it to `erase` violates `erase`'s precondition, which means that your program has [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Undefined behavior means that there is no guarantee on what the program will do (or whether it will compile at all) and therefore it is entirely possible that it *seems* to work until somewhere later in your program and/or that you get a segmentation fault. These are possible manifestations of undefined behavior.

---

Practically speaking, the `erase` call probably dereferences some pointer contained in the iterator that doesn't point to any element and that triggers the segmentation fault. But that is an implementation detail dependent on your standard library implementation and it doesn't really matter anyway, as the rules are given by the language and described above.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map::erase()` can take one of three types of parameters:

- iterator
- iterator range
- key value

You're passing an iterator but it is `end()`, which is one *past* the last element in the map. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) for `std::map:erase()`:

> The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end()
>   iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferenceable) cannot be used
>   as a value for pos.

So for `std::map::erase()` to work with an iterator the element pointed to must be a valid element *within* the map. Otherwise all bets are off and you can get ***undefined behaviour***.

Comment: I have mentioned the same but the question is different.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus You are trying to perform an operation that just isn't valid. That's the issue. `end()` points to the memory location that is one past the last element. Using `end()` with `erase()` violates the requirements of the parameters. Hence the seg fault in your case. `end()` is typically used for checking you are within the bounds of the map - like in a for loop or with algorithm functions.

Comment: the question is about the memory structure of the `map` being untouched.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus It doesn't matter that the memory structure of the map is untouched, but trying to delete something that is not in the map using the map's `erase()` function results in undefined behaviour.